# Google Cloud Bandwidth Charge for VM

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I Just Received $300 in Google Cloud for free Trial and i am planning to launch Virtual Server for Webserver.
I have used Price Calculator and selected VM & Storage within $300 for year. But I don't understand that I be be charged for Data Transfer between my VM to my website visitors. 
Will I be charged extra for Bandwidth..? I just planed to run only Web Server on VM.

Comment: Being this this is a billing question, it might be better suited to ask google?

Answer (score 3):

You can find GCP network pricing [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#network)

In your case, you will be charged for the traffic from your web server to visitors (egress) but not for the traffic from visitor to you (ingress).